# Does OSL work on the GPU?

Tags: gpu, osl

On [openshading](http://www.openshading.com/osl/faq/) the FAQ says:

*OSL only works on the CPU for now. It would be possible to port the system to GPU, but it would require a lot of work. There are no immediate plans for it.*

What does this mean? Does this affect only OSL script nodes? I noticed that a a OSL script wave_rot.osl is compiled in wave_rot.oso which looks like assembly source code (but not for ia64 so I guess it is code for CUDA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/OSL):

> Users can now create their own nodes using the [Open Shading Language](http://code.google.com/p/openshadinglanguage/) (OSL). Note that these nodes will only work for CPU rendering; there is no support for running OSL code on the GPU.

[Quote from Brecht](http://www.blenderdiplom.com/index.php/en/interviews/item/84-interview-brecht-van-lommel-on-cycles?tmpl=component&print=1):

> The main issue is to get OSL working on the GPU. It's almost as much work as building Cycles itself. It's not easy to do so we need more people to help us.

The oso file just contains the shader compiled [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode).

Comment: Thank you,I found another reference here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/OSL which also mentions the oso bytecode.